# Vector or diagram drawing webservice

Tags: web-services, charts

I have a webapp from which I'd like to insert diagrams and images quickly and easily.  I expect there is, somewhere out there, a webservice which will take a URL with a parameter that describes the vector graphics or diagram and returns an image.

No unlike what google charts does for graphing data.

Any resources or ideas on this?

If I had to build it myself, do you have some ideas of how I might accomplish that?

For instance, does PHP/asp/etc have a graphics library that's capable of rendering simple vector graphics?

-Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). Done by a bloke here in Australia.

Answer (score 1):

> No unlike what google charts does for graphing data.

Why not just use the Google Chart API?

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: It doesn't allow me to draw arbitrary vector graphics or diagrams.  Only graphs and a few other visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm to produce actual vector graphics on the client side, instead of making requests to a server?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to generate SVG in realtime in the browser.  This decreases browser compatibility, but that will decrease over time.

Comment: With the SVG plugin for IE, there is lots of support for all browsers.  Unfortunately IE8 Beta 2's performance with SVGs is so bad that one wonders if it will even be usable in IE8 RTM